# Using count in an eloquent query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
$data = User::where(function($q){
        $q->where(User::whereIn('access', array(1,2,3,4))->count(), 4);
    })->get();
```

I only want users who have an access of 1,2,3,4 (used this for illustrative purposes but this is usually a passed in array).

I am getting all users where the count of a where in query equals 4.

How can this be done in eloquent? My above code errors, as it is trying to select all from users where 4 = 4.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is access a field on the users table really?

Comment: Why don't you just `User::whereIn('access', $array)->get();`?

Comment: @Ben Beacuase it's not about finding those, but making sure a user have all - thus `count`. It's basically `get users with all the permissions`

Comment: And how are those "accesses" stored, as a string on a single `access` column?

Comment: Also, `where(User::whereIn('access', array(1,2,3,4))->count(), 4);` is getting you 4 users with `access` either being 1, 2, 3 or 4, not 1 user with all 4 accesses.

Comment: Don't worry about my table layouts, I really use lots of joins and pivot tables, but made a simple example for the question.

Comment: @panthro I don't, really. It just, your example makes no sense, so it will be hard to help.